# NSInvocation - How to figure out who the message was directed to from inside forwardInvocation:

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

Both sourceObject and destinationObject are instances of the SameClass. SameClass is a Singleton. Essentially the same object goes by two different names and has behavior at method level which is different based on that. I have these lines of code: 
(there is a symmetry here, I need them to call the same method but in two different places under two different circumstances)

```
//some code in some place
    [singleton1Object increase: 20];


//some code in a completely different place
    [singleton2Object increase: 40];
```

Neither singleton1Object or singleton2Object implement increase: instead they both use it to direct the message each in their respective directions (other objects)

```
forwardInvocation
- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation
{
    //determine where the message came from
}
```

Is there any way to determine which part of the code singleton1Object or singleton2Object initially received increase: and base my decision of where to route, on that, from inside forwardInvocation:?

NOTE: The Singleton send messages to itself he is both the sender and the receiver. He refers to itself by two or more names in code, stored in two of it's variable, he keeps doing this until it gets from method to method to one he does not understand in which case he forwards the message to another object. Where I am in the code, mainly determined by singleton1Object and singleton2Object or some other technique has the clue to where I should forward my messages. Edited the question see edit for more details.

Comment: Are you trying to get the sender pre or post forwarding?

Comment: The Singleton send messages to itself he is both the sender and the receiver. He keeps doing this until it gets to a method he does not understand in which case he forwards the message to another object. Where I am in the code, mainly determined by singleton1Object and singleton2Object has the clue to where I should forward my messages. Edited the question see edit for more details.

Comment: I'd suggest changing your design rather than trying to work around this path of confusion. An object referring to itself by _two different_ names, neither of which is `self` sounds nuts to me; it means you probably shouldn't have a singleton, but two instances of a class, or maybe even two separate derived classes.

Comment: @CodaFi I would like to get the sender post forwarding. However what do you mean by pre forwarding?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yes, you are right, the solution is a little nuts. I'm surprised it's even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `forwardInvocation`, `self` is the receiver of the message.

The invocation object does not contain information about the initial *sender* of the message.

Comment: Hmmm... I was looking at getting some info from where the message was sent. What does the [anInvocation target] contain then?

Comment: @unmircea: I am writing this on the phone, so I cannot tell you much more at present. Perhaps I misunderstood your question. Did you try checking `self`?

Comment: It's all right, I updated my question with a lot more details on the my weird predicament. Take you time...

Comment: @unmircea: If both pointers point to the same object then you cannot distinguish them.

Comment: I see, this is not good news, edited again with even more information. The Singleton send messages to itself he is both the sender and the receiver. He keeps doing this until it gets from method to method to one he does not understand in which case he forwards the message to another object. Where I am in the code, mainly determined by singleton1Object and singleton2Object has the clue to where I should forward my messages. Edited the question see edit for more details.

Comment: Please add that anInvocation from forwardInvocation: anInvocation does not contain any information about the initial sender of the message you intercepted, this way it answers the question and I can accept it.